# How would I obtain error information on a $Failed GeoElevationData?

Tags: warning-messages, geography

The following code returns an error: `GeoElevationData:` with no description of the error.  I think this error may be because I am asking for elevation data that is too granular.

```
cellGrid= Flatten[Table[{lat,lon}, {lat, 53.506, 53.508,0.0005},{lon,-112.097, -112.095,0.0005}],1]
elevationData = GeoElevationData[cellGrid]
```

When I look at the stack trace, I see an `...Throw[$Failed, "GeoElevationDataError".` There are no entries in Help for the `GeoElevationDataError`.

I will try a variation on this code, but, are there some good detailed sources for error information?

Comment: `cellGrid = 
 GeoPosition[
  Table[{lat, lon}, {lat, 53.506, 53.508, 
    0.0005}, {lon, -112.097, -112.095, 0.0005}]];
elevationData = GeoElevationData[cellGrid]`